# The socket connection was aborted. Wcf

Tags: c#, wcf, windows-server-2012

i'm getting Error while connecting to WCF Service
its a working Code i have just changed the Server
WCF Service hosted in Window Service 
Windows Service is Running

i have two Servers 
1. Server_1 with Windows Server 2012 R2 Standard
2. Server_2 with Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise

Call From Server_2 working Fine
but i'm Getting below Error from Server_1

The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:30:00'.

```
8/23/2019 15:22:33 Process_Word_Document 8/23/2019 15:22:33 
 8/23/2019 15:22:33 szWord_Operation_Ip : 192.168.1.126
 8/23/2019 15:22:33net.tcp://192.168.1.126/CalcService
 8/23/2019 15:22:33 Channel 
 8/23/2019 15:22:33 eRROR : The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:29:59.9687487'. 8/23/2019 15:22:33 eRROR : Exception type System.ServiceModel.CommunicationException Exception message: The socket connection was aborted. This could be caused by an error processing your message or a receive timeout being exceeded by the remote host, or an underlying network resource issue. Local socket timeout was '00:29:59.9687487'. Stack trace: 
 ---BEGIN InnerException--- 
 Exception type System.Net.Sockets.SocketException
 Exception message: An existing connection was forcibly closed by the remote host
 Stack trace: at System.Net.Sockets.Socket.Receive(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, SocketFlags socketFlags)
 at System.ServiceModel.Channels.SocketConnection.ReadCore(Byte[] buffer, Int32 offset, Int32 size, TimeSpan timeout, Boolean closing)
 ---END Inner Exception
```

checked Windows Firewall is Off

```
NetTcpBinding _binding = new NetTcpBinding();
_binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;
_binding.SendTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
_binding.ReceiveTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
_binding.OpenTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
_binding.CloseTimeout = new TimeSpan(0, 10, 0);
 EndpointAddress _endpoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://" + szWord_Operation_Ip + "/CalcService");
Channel = new ChannelFactory<Process_Word_Document.ICalcService>(_binding, _endpoint);
Process_Word_Document.ICalcService proxy = Channel.CreateChannel();
proxy.Update_Document_Properties(szFilePath);
Channel.Close();
Channel.Abort();
Channel = null;
```

Answer (score 0):

Would you mind sharing your service-side? It seems that there is something wrong with the service running status. Please ensure that the binding configuration between the server-side and the client-side is consistent. I suggest you test the service if it works by using WCFTestclient tool. Besides, please enable the windows feature for supporting NetTCP protocol.
[image]
[image]
At last, Don’t forget that the service address contains a port number.

> net.tcp://10.157.13.69:4386/myservice

Feel free to let me know if there is anything I can help with.

Comment: i already installed all the required features.                                                                    service address net.tcp://192.168.1.126/CalcService     not provided port number but its   working from other server

Comment: we could try to host the service in the other port number since the port number of this server(808) might be already in use or try to manually specify it. The default port number depends on the hosting environment

Comment: i have hosted WCF Service in Windows Service on Client Machine(192.168.1.126) OS Windows 8. service is Called from different Servers which are working fine. only one Server is giving above Error.

Comment: The same code works on other machines, and the error only happens on this machine? Is the nettcpbinding security mode of the server None?

Comment: Yes . _binding.Security.Mode = SecurityMode.None;

Comment: I did not run into this issue. Maybe we can try calling the service by adding service reference.

Comment: i tried with same. made 1 exe with same service reference and provide required parameters. its working fine from same server from where we get error

Comment: what is the auto-generated service endpoint address in the configuration file? is it we are using at present?

Comment: please Check  i have Updated log while calling the Service

Comment: What is the definition of the binding configuration on the server-side? Besides, could you please post more details about the successful call that adding service reference on Server_1?

Comment: same as posted in above Code